# Statistical test for # stores per capita - exact Poisson or t-test?

Tags: distributions, poisson-distribution

I have the population denominators for high (n = 28137) and low (n = 35167) deprivation areas in a city. I want to be able to compare the # of convenience stores per capita in high and low deprivation areas to see if there are more stores in one area versus another. There are n = 43 stores in high and n = 27 in low deprivation areas.

Am I correct in assuming these variables are Poisson and that an exact Poisson test in, say R could get me what I am looking for?

I am hesitant because stores aren't really a characteristic of residents themselves. I am thinking a t-test but these data are not normally distributed and it wouldn't get around the fact the stores are not a characteristic of people in the population...although perhaps, it could be argued, it is a feature of the population itself...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your conclusions might depend on how you model the relationship between people and stores, let's be explicit about that.

**One reasonable approach** that seems in the spirit of the question is to suppose that stores emerge randomly as a function of the population: each new person creates a chance $\lambda$ of a new store appearing.  More explicitly (and slightly more generally) let us posit that the distribution of the number of stores in an area with $n$ people is indeed Poisson with a parameter equal to $\lambda n$.

Under the null hypothesis of no difference between the two areas we would estimate $\lambda$ as the mean number of stores per person:

$$\hat{\lambda} = \frac{43 + 27}{28137 + 35167}.$$

**How consistent are the data with this hypothesis?**  One way to tell, without any further analysis, would be to simulate data for the numbers of stores given these two populations.  In such a simulation the numbers of stores in the first area would have a Poisson$(28137\hat{\lambda})$ distribution and the numbers in the second area would have a Poisson$(35167\hat{\lambda})$ distribution.  The simulation results would therefore look like the histograms in the figure below.  That figure marks the actual observations with vertical red lines: the numbers of stores appear to be high for the high deprivation area and low for the low deprivation area.

**We can formalize and quantify this appearance** by constructing a statistic that appropriately measures the differences in stores per capita.  A good one would be a Student T-like statistic that divides the difference in stores per capita (compared to the expected difference) by its standard deviation.  Denote the two areas by indexes $1$ and $2$, their populations by $n_1$ and $n_2,$ the (true but unknown) underlying rates $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2,$ and the total numbers of stores in the two areas by $X_1$ and $X_2.$   Assuming these numbers are statistically independent (which is a useful starting hypothesis), it follows that

$$\mathbb{E}(X_2 - X_1) = \lambda_2 n_2 - \lambda_1 n_1$$

and

$$\text{Var}(X_2 - X_1) = \text{Var}(X_1) + \text{Var}(X_2) = n_1 \lambda_1 + n_2 \lambda_2.$$

Under the null hypothesis that $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2,$ the mean $\mathbb{E}(X_2-X_1)$ is estimated as

$$\hat{\lambda} (n_2 - n_1) \approx 7.7736$$

and the variance will be estimated just as simply by

$$\widehat{\text{Var}}(X_2 - X_1) = X_1 + X_2 = 70$$

whence the T statistic is

$$T = \frac{27-43 - 7.7736}{\sqrt{70}} \approx -2.8415.$$

A normal approximation to its distribution is accurate because both store counts are fairly large. Because the alternative hypothesis is only that the two rates might differ, this *two-sided test* gives a p-value of $2\Phi(-|-2.8415|) \approx 0.00449,$ which is small: **the difference looks significant**.   The simulation provides a check: in $10,000$ iterations, I found only $40$ of them, or $0.004$ of the total, exhibited a T statistic larger in absolute value than the one actually observed.  (The values of $\pm 2.8415$ are shown in the histogram of these statistics.)  This is close agreement with the Normal approximation.

In summary, **these data are not consistent with the model and the additional hypotheses made in the foregoing analysis.**  Therefore at least one of the following is not true:

- The store counts do not even approximately have Poisson distributions with rates proportional to the populations; and/or
- The store counts are not independent.

In either case it would be fair to say there is a "significant difference" in the per-capita numbers of stores in these two regions.

[image: Figures]

`R` code to produce the calculations and figures follows.

```r
#
# Data
#
people <- c(High=28137, Low=35167)
stores <- c(High=43, Low=27)
#
# Estimates and tests.
#
lambda <- sum(stores)/sum(people)
n <- 10^4
sim <- matrix(rpois(n*length(stores), lambda*people), ncol=length(stores), byrow=TRUE)
colnames(sim) <- c("High", "Low")

t.stat <- function(stores, people) {
  m = diff(sum(stores)/sum(people) * people)
  (diff(stores) - m) / sqrt(sum(stores))
}

t.sim <- apply(sim, 1, t.stat, people=people)
sum(abs(t.sim) > abs(t.stat(stores, people))) / n # The simulation p-value
2 * pnorm(-abs(t.stat(stores, people)))           # The normal approximation
#
# Figures
#
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
plot.sim <- function(s) {
  hist(sim[, s], freq=FALSE, main=paste(s, "deprivation simulation"), xlab="Stores")
  #abline(v=(lambda * people)[s], col="Blue")
  abline(v=stores[s], col="Red", lwd=2)
}
plot.sim("High"); plot.sim("Low")
hist(t.sim, main="T statistic in simulation", xlab="T", freq=FALSE)
abline(v = t.stat(stores, people)*c(-1,1), col="Red", lwd=2)
```

Comment: Yes, we could just apply a Poisson GLM, but I offer this more elaborate answer to show how the problem can be resolved using elementary statistical reasoning and methods.

Comment: Thanks! Running an exact Poisson gives me a significant p-value for the rate ratio difference (similar to that for your t-test). I wasn't sure how to code the t-test, so thanks for the code, all the code actually